responses of my pagination feature somewhy requests only the first page
It feels like every scrapy.Request I make just doesn't exist after the first one and the response argument is somewhy always the response to the first request even if the method was called by another request.
The loop is endless because I can't catch the last api page because all of the requests are to the first page, why is it this way?
from typing import Iterable
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider   

class ScrollSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scroll'

    page = 1
    headers={
        # this API requires these headers:
        "Referer": "https://web-scraping.dev/testimonials",
        "X-Secret-Token": "secret123",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(f'https://web-scraping.dev/api/testimonials?page=1', headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse)

    
    def parse(self, response):
        if response.status != 200:
            raise CloseSpider(f'Receive {response.status} status code')
        
        testimonials = response.css('div.testimonial')
        for testimonial in testimonials:
            yield {
                'user_name': testimonial.css('identicon-svg::attr("username")').get(),
                'testimonial': testimonial.css('p::text').get(),
                'rating': len(testimonial.css('span svg').getall())
            }

        self.page += 1 
        url = f'https://web-scraping.dev/api/testimonials?page{self.page}'
        yield response.follow(url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse)


You should have read the logs.

You have a typo at the bottom of your code:
[...]
        self.page += 1 
        url = f'https://web-scraping.dev/api/testimonials?page{self.page}' # <-- Missing '=' after 'page'

